# JSF ManagedBean initialisation fails

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am new to JSF and I'm facing a severe problem since yesterday. The following method 'initialiseLists' is called via

```
<f:event listener="#{Bean.initialiseLists}" type="postAddToView" />
```

from my view

```
public void initialiseLists() {
  this.setAuthorisationsToDelete(new ArrayList<>());

  this.setRoles(new RoleManager().readAll());
  this.setReportIntervals(new ReportIntervalManager().readAll());

  AddUserCustomerBundle bundle = new AddUserCustomerBundle(new CustomerManager().readActive());

  System.out.println("");

  this.setAddKundeAuth(bundle);
}
```

If I deploy the Bean with this code on Tomcat7 in Eclipse everything works fine. But you may ask 'Why did he put the System.out.println("") there?'.

The really strange thing is, that I get an errormessage, if I comment the sysout.

```
/WEB-INF/common/createOrEdit.xhtml @14,72 listener="#{Bean.initialiseLists}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'Bean' resolved to null
```

After uncommenting the sysout and restarting tomcat, it works fine again. Can anyone tell me, where I could get further information about the cause of the error? It seems to me, that my Bean couldn't be initialised. The Java Stacktrace doesn't yield anything interesting...

```
Feb 27, 2015 10:05:11 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: JSF1073: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException erfasst während Verarbeitung von RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=/WEB-INF/common/createOrEdit.xhtml @14,72 listener="#{Bean.initialiseLists}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'Bean' resolved to null
Feb 27, 2015 10:05:11 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: /WEB-INF/common/createOrEdit.xhtml @14,72 listener="#{Bean.initialiseLists}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'Bean' resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/common/createOrEdit.xhtml @14,72 listener="#{Bean.initialiseLists}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'Bean' resolved to null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(Unknown Source)    
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent.processListener(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at de.frupek.fluidman.web.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Edit1: I get the error now if I'm adding another property to my bean, e.g.

```
private int test;
```

Could it be an environment problem (tomcat7, eclipse, ubuntu, etc...)?

Edit2: It seems to be a problem to use java.util.function.Function in my Bean. If I comment all occurrences, everything is working fine, if I add something like

```
Function<User, List<Customer>> f = User::getCustomers;
```

the above exception is thrown. Are there any Java 8 restrictions in JSF usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours I was able to "solve" my issue, the "solution" works but isn't very satisfactory: I had to copy the cited method initialiseLists and another method which uses the class-member bundle to the end of my sourcefile. My bean is now correctly initialised (with all my t:param stuff) and it works perfectly.

I've got no idea, which component caused that special behaviour and I hope, I won't face it anymore. My guess is, that any JSF class fails while "scanning" my bean, but it could be completely wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I assume your class is called `Bean` and you haven't provided an alias for it, which will force JSF to register it with the alias `bean`.

In the `<f:event>`, change `Bean` with `bean`:

```
<f:event listener="#{bean.initialiseLists}" type="postAddToView" />
```

Alternatively, you can name your bean `Bean` like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "Bean")
public class Bean { ... }
```

and keep the current expression in the `<f:event>`'s listener attribute.

Comment: Bean comes from <t:param name="Bean" value="#{userDetailBean}"/>. The strange thing is, that it works correctly, with the uncommented sysout (without changes in my view component).

Comment: I wouldn't believe my own words if I wasn't able to reproduce it... Which options do I have to debug? As said, I'm very new to JSF...

Comment: You can also try to change the expression to `<f:event listener="#{userDetailBean.initialiseLists}" type-"postAddToView" />`. Then redeploy the application and check if it works.

Comment: I could not do this easily, because the listener is defined in another *.xhtml file. From the problematic *.xhtml the Bean param is set and a t:define Tag is filled with the specific data. Is there any possibility to debug the EL resolving which obviously fails?

Comment: Ok, now there's another problem with similar behaviour: If I use Java 8 function references (e.g. User::getCustomers) in any method of my Bean, I get the same error as before. All of my projects use java-8-oracle and are configured to source level 1.8. The code compiles but fails on Bean initialisation (that's my guess).

Comment: @Julius I can't understand why are you using  `<t:param name="Bean" value="#{userDetailBean}"/>` why not using directly "userDetailBean"? Or if it's a managed property why not just  `@ManagedProperty` or `f:viewparam` ? and what is the scope of your bean?

Comment: I'm using the same form template for several Beans. On every single *.xhtml the Bean has to be set and a custom form has to be provided. The f:event is defined in the form template *.xhtml

Comment: Behaviour is the same if I use userDetailBean directly... Does anyone know how to debug or log the EL Resolver steps?